# how to delete rows where a single column value is duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to remove all rows having duplicated `title` column. Something like:

```
delete from clients where title is duplicated
```

For example, if five rows have the same `title` column - four of them shold be deleted.

How to do this?

Comment: your clients  table have a pk  ??

Comment: @scaisEdge - yes it has a pk

Comment: I have posted  an answer  .. hope is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a unique column like `id` or `somedate`:

```
delete c 
from clients c inner join clients cc
on cc.title = c.title and cc.id < c.id
```

This code will keep the row with the minimum id among the duplicates.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/6).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you clients table have as pk the column id  delete all the rows  wotn same title  but with id <> from max(id)

```
delete c
from clients c
LEFT JOIN  (
    select  max(id) max_id, title 
    from  clients 
    group by title  
) t on t.title  = c.title 
    and t.max_id  = c.id 
where t.max_id is null
```

Comment: getting error - `#1054 - Unknown column 't._max_id' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the one with lowest ID:

```
DELETE cl1 FROM clients cl1, clients cl2 WHERE cl1.title = cl2.title AND cl1.id > cl2.id
```

If you want to keep the one with highest ID:

```
DELETE cl1 FROM clients cl1, clients cl2 WHERE cl1.title = cl2.title AND cl1.id < cl2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
DELETE c1 FROM clients c1 INNER JOIN clients c2 WHERE c1.id < c2.id AND c1.title = c2.title;
```

This query will delete the other 4 rows and keep the row with highest id.

Answer (score 0):

After using the following as suggested by forpas ...

```sql
   DELETE c 
   FROM clients c INNER JOIN clients cc
   ON cc.title = c.title AND cc.id < c.id;
```

... you will probably want to add a unique key to prevent duplicates in future:

```sql
    ALTER TABLE clients ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I give a solution for a table without a primary/unique key:

```
delete c
from clients c
cross join (select @titles := '') init
where find_in_set(sha2(title, 224), @titles) or
      length(
        @titles := concat(
          @titles, ',', sha2(title, 224)
        )
      ) < 0;
```

Test it online with [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5TWYB55BTB8Wn9XFD45T8b/1).